# nmap is not showing hostnames

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, bind, nmap

I am new to linux, and I am trying to get all the hostnames from the hosts of my local network.

I was trying the command:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24
```

and also:

```
sudo nmap -sn -R 192.168.0.0/24
```

but the only hostname I get is the one from my router.

I was thinking that maybe the router doesn’t have a DNS server and because of that it can’t provide this info to nmap.

The router was provided by the ISP.
I checked if the port 53 of the router was opened. It was!
I don't know if what I want is even possible given this router.

Maybe someone could help me out?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details

Comment: If he's using ubuntu from the last 10 years, I can't see how release details affect this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS server doesn't magically generate hostnames.  Something has to configure DNS with those hostnames.  Both forward and reverse hostnames have to be configured in DNS to get full functionality.

DNS doesn't generally support automatic dynamic hostnames.  Protocols like mDNS/DNS-SD implemented by avahi try to do this, but it only works for participating hosts on a local network.

Hostnames have two sources, and those sources do not have to match.  One source is hostnames assigned to IP addresses through an external authority and configured into DNS, and no host has to actually exist at those ip/hostname pairs.  The other source is the name the host calls itself, and this can only be obtained by probing the host or listening to announcements by the the host through protocols like SMB or mDNS.

Comment: What I want is to find the name hosts give to themselves, from hosts that exist inside my local network. I thought nmap already fetched that.

Comment: nmap only probes the hosts.  If it gets a name, it gets it by asking the system to reverse resolve the name.   Typically on a linux system, nsswitch.conf controls what is used to reverse resolve it, and dns and mdns are both in the list.  But if a host doesn't speak mdns, you won't get a result that way.